# PHP - Adding Exception To Script

Tags: php, exception

Okay, so a program I use uses PHP scripts.  I have it set to name clips a specific way but sometimes we need to change it to add an additional character.

Right now, the clip is renamed as: ***20_1 (XA)*** based on the info below:

```
Scene: 20
Take: 1
Slate:
Clipname: XA001C001.mov
Select:
```

And this is the script to do that:

```
function GenerateClipname($Scene,$Slate,$Take,$ClipName,$Select)
{
    global $link;
    global $NoSCounter;
    global $NoTCounter;

    $sql="SELECT count(ID) AS Counter FROM shots WHERE Scene='".SqlEscape($Scene)."' AND Select='".SqlEscape($Select)."' AND Take='".SqlEscape($Take)."'";
    $ScanResult=mysql_query($sql,$link);
    $ScanRow = mysql_fetch_array($ScanResult);
    if ($Scene=="")
    {
        $Scene=sprintf("NoScene_%d",$NoSCounter);
        $NoSCounter++;
    }
    if ($Take=="")
    {
        $Take=sprintf("NoTake_%d",$NoTCounter);
        $NoTCounter++;
    }
    $Name=$Scene;
    if ($Take!="") $Name.="_".$Take;
    if ($ClipName!="")
    {
        $Name=$Name." "."(".(strtoupper(substr($ClipName,0,2))).")";    
    }

    if ($Select) $Name.="*";
    return $Name;
}
```

The exception I would like to add is if the original Clipname only had 1 Alpha character at the beginning (A001C001.mov) then the script would label the clip as ***20_1 (A)*** but if it had two, even three Alpha characters, then it would add that. I know the part of the script that needs to be affected is:

```
if ($ClipName!="")
    {
        $Name=$Name." "."(".(strtoupper(substr($ClipName,0,2))).")";    
    }
```

If needed, I can provide more of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine preg_match and strpos like this:

```
function findFirstNonDigitPart($str) {
  $pat = '(\d+)';
  preg_match($pat,$str,$matches);
  if(count($matches) == 0) {
      return false;
  }
  $pos = strpos($str,$matches[0]);  
  return substr($str,0,$pos);
}


$str = "XSA1234234asfaf";
echo findFirstNonDigitPart($str);
```

in your case it would be (paste the function somewhere in your script):

```
if ($ClipName!="") {
    $part = findFirstNonDigitPart($ClipName);
    if($part === false) {
        throw new Exception("Something wrong with the clipname");
    }
    $Name=$Name." "."(".strtoupper($part).")";    
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, exactly where would I add that within the script I provided above? I'm giving somethings a try but of course, I'm very new to this

Comment: Thanks! I will paste both into the script and let you know how it goes! :)

Comment: I was able to get this to work with the information you provided above :). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($ClipName!="")
{
    $pattern = '#^(\\p{L}{1,3}).?*$#'; // group(letter chars, case insensitive, lenght 1-3) + other 
    $prefix = preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $ClipName); // take matching (first) group as replacement if present
    if ($prefix == $ClipName) {
        // nothing extracted (no matching prefix)
    } else {
        $Name=$Name." "."(".(strtoupper($prefix).")";
    }
}
```

Don't know how you want to deal with various names (no $prefix for example) + other patterns just in case:

`'#^([a-zA-Z]{1,3}).?*$#'` - english alphabet chars only

`'#^([a-zA-Z]+).?*$#'` - english, unlimited lenght (same as `[A-Z]{1,}`)

Comment: Thanks for this. I will have to try this in the morning.  The name will always be named using Clipname so it can use that prefix :).  I'm still very new to scripting and teaching myself while looking for classes. I enjoy this stuff and take what I can from all of this so thank you!

Comment: My first try I wasn't able to get this to work.  I mess around with it and see if there is something I am doing incorrectly. However, I was able to get the script below from @steven to work :). Thanks!